# Finding the image of $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \frac{4x}{x+1}$

Tags: proof-writing

I need to find the image of the function $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \frac{4x}{x+1}$.

What I did was make the function in terms if y to end up with:

$x = \dfrac{y}{4-y}$

Now, I don't know how to go from here. I know that y can't equal $4$, but how do I prove that without using calculus.

Also, what is the double subset technique? Apparently I am supposed to use it for this question but I don't know exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $x\in (0,\infty)$, $0\lt\frac{x}{1+x}\lt1$. Thus $0\lt\frac{4x}{1+x}\lt4$

Comment: Why didn't you multiply the denominator by 4?

Comment: I multiplied the whole inequality by 4. not numerator and denominator.